# Question about changing the order of integration

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a question considering the change of integration order.

Let $I_x,I_y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

what I know is if a function f(x,y) is integratable on $I_x$ and $I_y$ and the Integrals over those both Integrals are finite, then one can change the integration order
$\int_{I_x} (\int_{I_y} f(x,y)dy) dx= \int_{I_y} (\int_{I_x} f(x,y)dx) dy$

But how about a Integral that looks like

$\int_{I_x} (\int_{I_y} f(x,y)dy) g(x,y) dx$

Does this change of order look like this?

$\int_{I_y} (\int_{I_x} g(x,y)dx) f(x,y) dy$

Comment: are you integrating over rectangles or general sets?

Comment: @LiterallyanOrange over rectangles

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem